# How to call Form_Load of one form from another form in Access VBA

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, events

I have a  MS Access  form which displays list of records in grid . Each row is having a **detail** buttton.

When clicked on it , it **opens up a new form** with details of that particular selected row.

When click on **close** button of detail form , **the values get saved to database.**

Now , on click of close , i would like **to execute Form Load of main form** . This is because i need to **refresh** some values after update is made in detail form

**I have tried some thing like this :**

```
Call Forms!frm_Package!Form_Load
```

Please suggest on how to accomplish this . I have tried various ways but could not get it worked.

Please let me know if any further information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you could not "`re-call`" the Load is because it is a `Private Sub` and only when you are inside the Form you can access the method.

One way to hack "***external procedure call***" is to move the code inside the Form Load into a Public Sub (withing the same Form) and then calling the newly created Sub from outside the form. Like,

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

**TO**

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    newPubMethod
End Sub

Public Sub newPubMethod()
    MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

Now you will be able to call this Public Sub newPubMethod even from outside the Form with the right quantifiers.

```
Private Sub exitButtonName_Click()
    Forms("CallingFormName").newPubMethod
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me . thanks ..accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to do this kind of things. I hide the main form when i open a popup form ...  i do my work and then i return to the main form.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
If gIsLoaded("mainForm") Then Form_mainForm.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Close()
' -- here you will put the code you need!!!
If gIsLoaded("mainForm") Then Form_mainForm.Visible = True
End Sub

Function gIsLoaded(strName As String, Optional _
                                      lngtype As AcObjectType = acForm) As Boolean
    gIsLoaded = (SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, _
                        lngtype, strName) <> 0)

End Function
```